# Rundeck Job Reference - Using a variable as Job Name

Tags: rundeck

I'm trying to assemble a system which will require multiple jobs being run in a variable number of nodes in a variable order with possibility for duplication.

I'm attempting to solve this by having a single job for each node (note each node runs different jobs as well) and then having which job is executed decided at runtime.

But when running the job I get:

```
"2: Workflow step executing: JobReferenceItem{label='Step 1 job, jobIdentifier='${data.DEPLOY_SYSTEM_1}', nodeStep=true}"
```

The variable doesn't seem to be getting expanded. Is this not possible or could I be doing it wrong? I've not been able to find any information on using variables to dynamically choose which job is run

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're right, I tested calling using data and option variable on Job Reference Step and doesn't work:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>97979d11-6ff8-45ef-9843-8b90e4e135d1</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>JobONE</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "MYJOB=JobTWO"</exec>
        <plugins>
          <LogFilter type='key-value-data'>
            <config>
              <logData>true</logData>
              <regex>^(MYJOB)\s*=\s*(.+)$</regex>
            </config>
          </LogFilter>
        </plugins>
      </command>
      <command>
        <exec>echo ${data.MYJOB}</exec>
      </command>
      <command>
        <jobref name='${data.MYJOB}' nodeStep='true'>
          <useName>true</useName>
        </jobref>
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>97979d11-6ff8-45ef-9843-8b90e4e135d1</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

A good workaround is to embed [RD CLI](https://rundeck.github.io/rundeck-cli/) command to call the job (using the data or option) on inline script step  like this:

```xml
<joblist>
  <job>
    <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
    <description></description>
    <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
    <id>97979d11-6ff8-45ef-9843-8b90e4e135d1</id>
    <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
    <name>JobONE</name>
    <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
    <plugins />
    <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
    <sequence keepgoing='false' strategy='node-first'>
      <command>
        <exec>echo "MYJOB=JobTWO"</exec>
        <plugins>
          <LogFilter type='key-value-data'>
            <config>
              <logData>true</logData>
              <regex>^(MYJOB)\s*=\s*(.+)$</regex>
            </config>
          </LogFilter>
        </plugins>
      </command>
      <command>
        <exec>echo ${data.MYJOB}</exec>
      </command>
      <command>
        <script><![CDATA[# call another job, more info: rd run help
rd run -j @data.MYJOB@ -p ProjectLOCAL]]></script>
        <scriptargs />
      </command>
    </sequence>
    <uuid>97979d11-6ff8-45ef-9843-8b90e4e135d1</uuid>
  </job>
</joblist>
```

Using Ruleset (only for Rundeck Enterprise) you can decide the way depending on the value of some variable, take a [look](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/workflow-strategies/ruleset.html#examples).

Also, you can suggest that issue in the [official GitHub space](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues).